# broadcast receiver error custom intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm doing something I thought would be simple as have done a broadcast receiver in the past on 2.3.4 droid.  I'm using 4.x now in this little program.

Here is the main architecture/flow.  I want/have a receiver to be listening for a custom broadcast/intent.  I created this as a stand along project/apk

```
public class FileIntegrityMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
public String CLASS_NAME = "FileIntegrityMonitor";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "Entered onReceive: got broadcast from startFIM");

    String actionReceived = intent.getAction();
    Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "Action received=" + actionReceived);

    if (actionReceived.equals(StartFIMActivity.CUSTOM_INTENT))
    {
        //start service to perform the file integrity check
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "start service to perform file integrity check");  


    }


}
```

Then I created a activity as a separate project/app as a driver for now to kick the broadcast receiver off. Will probably replace with something else later but wanted to get the mechanics/comms down now.
    public class StartFIMActivity extends Activity 
    {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "com.kdms2.StartFIM.intent.action.start";
    public String CLASS_NAME = "StartFIMActivity";

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "Entered onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES); //api  3.1+
    i.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
    Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "send  brodcast to monitor");
    this.sendBroadcast(i);

}
}
```

Now in the trace I do get the intent in FileIntegrityMonitor but a strange message that it's trying to run some method and I don't know why.  Error is:
E/AndroidRuntime(979): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.kdms2.FileIntegrityMonitor.StartFIMActivity: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.kdms2.FileIntegrityMonitor.StartFIMActivity

why did it add the class name of the activity that broadcast the action to the broadcast receiver?

Is it something in the manifest (receiver)?

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <receiver android:name=".StartFIMActivity" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="99999999999">
            <action android:name="com.kdms2.StartFIM.intent.action.start"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

activity manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:name=".StartFIMActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>  

</application>

</manifest>
```

v/r,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Your receiver's name is `FileIntegrityMonitor`, but in the manifest you try to register `StartFIMActivity` as both the `<activity>` and `<receiver>` elements.  Probably oughta be:

```
<receiver android:name=".FileIntegrityMonitor" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="99999999999">
        <action android:name="com.kdms2.StartFIM.intent.action.start"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Or something of the like.

HTH

Comment: Yup your right! changed it then got java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.kdms2.FileIntegrityMonitor.FileIntegrityMonitor

Comment: Think I found the issue.  Namespace issue.  Had default package name and not package com.kdms2.FileIntegrityMonitor